# TextBox.TextProperty vs TextBox.Text in wpf

Tags: wpf

If we see definition of TextBox in wpf we can find 2 property, TextProperty & other just Text property,  are they are same or any difference?

Answer (score 1):

TextProperty is static. It is the dependency property for Text that is registered with the property management system in WPF for the TextBox type. This registration allows the property to be involved in binding, change tracking and value resolution. The Text property is a plain old C# property used to hold the Text value for a particular instance of the TextBox.

For more information about Dependency properties see this excellent page: http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html

Comment: I can understand its a Dependency property,but confusion is TextBox.Text is a wrapper around TextBoxProperty(Dependency one) like public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

Comment: In WPF at runtime we get a massive visual tree. In summary, the logical tree that you declare in your xaml gets expanded into what's displayed via Control templates, Data templates etc etc. A humble button even has a fair tree of sub elements. If all of these elements stored all their own data we'd use a fair bit of memory and it wouldn't be efficient if we changed a parent property and wanted all children to change too. On top of this, animations and styles can change values as well so the reason for the getter setter wiring is to let the property system keep track of the effective value.

Comment: Thanks James for your response, but my question is the simple CLR Text property is wrapper around Dependency Property(TextProperty) or not?

Comment: Yes it is but the dependency property needs to be registered for it to work.

Comment: Ohhk.That means in order to use Dependency property, do we need a baking CLR property in wpf XAML?

Comment: You don't technically need the CLR property I guess. The inheritance chain provides GetValue and SetValue via DependencyObject. But just treat them like a complimentary pair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76284/discussion-between-debashish-tripathy-and-james-lucas).

Comment: last, Just wanted to know why WPF system have defined both TextBox.Text & TextBox.Property, It would be ok if it has ommitted the Text property what you think